# MVC Routing for domain name only

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, routes

I have MVC 3 application and I want to know how to set the domain name to route to specific controller and action (without specify them), e.g.
MyDomain.com to route to controller -> Landing, action -> landing.

The application is hosted on IIS 6.

Regards,
may.

Comment: You want to change routing based on the domain name?

Answer (score 0):

You want to change the parameter defaults in the default route in global.asax:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Landing", action = "Landing", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

Comment: Hi, I already checked that, but it's not working. I got blank page/ or error 404.

Comment: Do you have a LandingController with the following method?

    public ActionResult Landing()

This method works fine for me